# Close window is not destroying the panel

Tags: extjs4

When I click on cross button window is closing but panel data is not getting destroyed. When I open fresh window it opens with old data.

Code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                            title: 'Address Management',
                            height: 480,
                            width: 500,
                            closeAction: 'close',
                             id:'Edit',
                            resizable: true,
                            items: [{xtype : 'AddAddressPanel'}],            
                            }).show();
```

I tried with this also:

```
closeAction: 'hide',
```

But again same problem. Could you please let me know what should be done?

Answer (score 1):

The API docs for [Ext.panel.Panel closeAction configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-closeAction) describes two possible values:

- `destroy`: Remove the window from the DOM and destroy it and all descendant Components. The window will not be available to be redisplayed via the show method.
- `hide`: Hide the window by setting visibility to hidden and applying negative offsets. The window will be available to be redisplayed via the show method.

Since `destroy` is the default you can just drop the `closeAction` configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this config line:

```
closeAction: 'close',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works after removing the above config line... :)